# What is the earliest mention of an alternate reality in Marvel comics?

Tags: marvel, comics

Over the years, Marvel has explored a lot of characters and possibilities using alternate realities. Now, there are a [whole lot of alternate universes](http://marvel.wikia.com/Multiverse/Universe_Listing) in [the Marvel Multiverse](http://marvel.wikia.com/Multiverse), and characters now frequently cross over between realities and timelines.

Excluding *What If?* and obvious parody comics, what is the earliest mention of an alternate reality in Marvel comics?

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the Avengers meeting the Squadron Supreme in *Avengers* #85 (Feb. 1971).

One of the first ongoing series that explicitly took place in an alternate future would be Killraven, starting in *Amazing Adventures* vol. 2, #18 (May 1973).

Answer (score 1):

### 1940.

The alternate dimension of [Kalahia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kalahia) first appeared in 1940, in [Mystic Comics #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic_Comics_Vol_1_4). Mystic Comics was published by [Timely Comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timely_Comics), which was later renamed Marvel Comics.